# index of array decrementing

Tags: java, android

So i'm stuck with this problem for a couple of hours. i have basically an array of textviews and want to swipe between them. the array i have is from 0 to 19. The fact is that incrementing works perfect, but when i decrement at value of [0] the index goes to [-1] so it crashes.

I need to do something in order that when i get to index[0] and decrement the index to jump back to [19].

here is the code and my try with if else. Thanks a lot!!!

```
    mPreviousButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prev_btn);
    mPreviousButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex - 1) % mShowTipsTextBank.length;
            if (mCurrentIndex < 19) {
                mCurrentIndex = 19;
                updateQuestion();
            } else

                updateQuestion();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mPreviousButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prev_btn);
    mPreviousButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCurrentIndex--;
            if (mCurrentIndex < 0)
                mCurrentIndex = mShowTipsTextBank.length - 1;
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also a one liner.

**Decrement:**

```
mCurrentIndex = (mShowTipsTextBank.length + (mCurrentIndex - 1)) % mShowTipsTextBank.length;
```

**Increment:**

```
mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mShowTipsTextBank.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `if (mCurrentIndex < mShowTipsTextBank.length) {` will always be `true`.

You can check if the current index is 0 and set it to the last index of your array directly otherwise just decrement it

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex == 0 ? mShowTipsTextBank.length-1 : (mCurrentIndex - 1));
    updateQuestion();    
}
```

Note that the modulo operation is useless since `mCurrentIndex` should always be inferior than the `length` of your array (if you made the appropriate check when you incremented it).

Comment: yes, you're right. i should have checked against 19 in the first place. i am testing your code right now. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mCurrentIndex == 0){
    mCurrentIndex = 19;
}else{
    mCurrentIndex--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex - 1) % mShowTipsTextBank.length;
        if (mCurrentIndex < 0) {
            mCurrentIndex = 19;
            updateQuestion();
        } else
           {
            updateQuestion();
           }
```